# How to make jQuery getJSON work with Json.NET JavaScriptDateTimeConverter

Tags: jquery, date, datetime, json.net, getjson

ASP.NET's Json serializer spits out "/Date(1240718400000)/" for DateTime. In my Knockout viewmodel (that uses getJson and the knockout mapper) I used to deal with this with a writable computed that would convert this to an actual javascript date and back.

However, I'm not very happy with this solution as it clutters my viewmodel too much.

I decided to go with Json.NET and it's JavaScriptDateTimeConverter that gives me Date(1240718400000). In theory this is great as it would give me observables with real javascript dates.

In practice, I can't get it to work :(

I know this is invalid Json, and it seems the internal Json parser that jQuery uses, does not accept this.

Is there a way to make jQuery getJson work with Json.NET JavaScriptDateTimeConverter?

Comment: Moment.js supports .NET DateTime strings out of the box: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I didn't know this, but unfortunately this does not solve my problem. I would still need a writable computed in between my UI and my viewmodel, to convert between javascript dates and serialized dates, and that's what I want to get rid of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to take this approach:

My viewmodel has the JavaScriptDateTimeConverter on the DateTime property

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
public DateTime TheEndOfTheWorld { get; set; }
```

My controller returns a [JsonNetResult](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net)

```
return new JsonNetResult()
{
    Data = new MayaCalendar();
};
```

And finally, my javascript parses this to

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Calendars/Maya",
    dataType: "text",
}).done(function (data) {
    var json = eval("(" + data + ")");
    var viewmodel = new WeirdCalendarViewModel(json);
    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
});
```

In short:

1. I'm using JavaScriptDateTimeConverter to return an invalid JSON string, that contains new Date(7919938800000) instead of "/Date(7919938800000)/"
2. I call the method with $.ajax, dataType "text" so jQuery won't try to parse the invalid JSON
3. I do the parsing myself, using eval(), before I pass the object to my knockout viewmodel.
4. Lunch

Pro:

- The knockout mapper gets to work with true javascript dates, instead of strings

Con:

- eval()

Answer (score 0):

use this function to convert dates from json format to java script dates

```
function renderDate(value) {        
    var getDate;
    if (Date.parse(value)) {
        getDate = new Date(value);
    }

    //used for json date format like /Date(1224043200000)/
    else {
        getDate = new Date(parseInt(value.substr(6)));
    }
    //can decide the format here
    return ((getDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + getDate.getDate() + "-" + getDate.getFullYear());
}
```

Comment: I know how to convert those dates, but that's not my issue. I would like getJson to parse my invalid "new date" notation that the JavaScriptDateTimeConverter yields, so I can use the Knockout mapper to create an observable from a true javascript date

Answer (score 0):

you can serialize in Json.NET to get the same date format using

```
JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings  {   DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat    };
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourDataClass, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
```

I think start with that , as a small step 
And than continue to other changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [excellent article](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html) that provides a global solution for dealing with JSON dates.  It only deals with the ISO and .NET (/DATE(...)/) formats but could easily be modified to deal with JavaScriptDateTimeConverter's new Date(...) format as well.

The solution achieves this by overriding jquery's parseJSON method while maintaining backward compatibility.  Pretty cool.